# php to javascript int variable parsing

Tags: php, javascript, int

I am trying to parse an int value from php into a javascript variable but it is not working.

The first alert correctly displays the int value, but the second says "undefined". How can you parse the php variable correctly into the variable "test" as an integer? I tried parseInt but it didn't work. The value is for a graph so I need to at some point use the fillRect() command, the alerts are for testing only. Thanks.

```
    alert('<?php echo( $graph_max_max_value ); ?>');
    var test = <?php $graph_max_max_value; ?>
    alert(test);
```

Comment: Try var test = <?php echo $graph_max_max_value; ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var test = <?php echo $graph_max_max_value; ?>;` should work.

This outputs using `echo`, which you forgot, *and* adds the statement terminating semi-colon at the end.

Comment: @user1334130, make sure this value is supposed to be an integer. If it's not, use this : var test = "<?php echo $graph_max_max_value; ?>";

Comment: Thanks Grant. Now it works perfectly. :) Will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @TWCrap yes but the answer from Thomas was more helpful.

Comment: @user1334130, it's your call, and if you find that, then you should do that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to do anything to output the variable.

You want an `echo`, `print`, `printf`, etc.

(You also need to make sure that the data in PHP conforms to the syntax for a Number type in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var test = <?php echo $graph_max_max_value; ?>,
```

and then

```
alert(test);
```

If you dont use echo then the value is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an **echo** and you need to make sure you pass an integer value to your variable.

```
<script>
    <?php $graph_max_max_value = 1024;?>
    alert('<?php echo( $graph_max_max_value ); ?>');
    var test = '<?php echo $graph_max_max_value;?>';
    test.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    alert(test);
</script>
```